# AngularJS dynamic select inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm printing a list of products in a table. This list of products has a product type (`typeId`). I want to be able to change the `typeId` of the product directly in the table by using a select input.

The problem comes when I try to set the default option of the product in the select input, because It shoud be the option with the `typeId`.

`ng-repeat="x in screensList"`. The x represents a product.

I tried using ng-init or ng-value, but it won't work. What value should be in the ng-model of each select?

Code and images:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in screensList">
      <th scope="row">
        {{x.pantalla}}
      </th>
      <td>
        {{x.description}}
      </td>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control" ng-model="slideshowSelect" ng-options="y.title for y in slideshowsList track by y.id">
         </select>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">
         <button type="button" ng-click="deleteService($event)" serviceId="{{x.id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Colored code:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: What represents the product here. `x`? BTW you're using `x` as variable in the outer iteration and `x` too in the inner iteration (the one for the select). You should change one of them to a different name.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes, X is the product. And yes, I'll change it ASAP, it should have a different name, but the problem is still there!

Comment: Replace `ng-model="slideshowSelect"` of <select> with `ng-model="screensList[$index].typeId"?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="x.idSlideshow" ng-options="y.id as y.title for y in slideshowsList">
 </select>
```

Check the working example: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/no6b47wz/1/)